# how to get the items with maximal score in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have this list:

```
lista = [([('autorità', 'S'), ('competente', 'A')], 580.0), ([('legislazione', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 313.0), ([('età', 'S'), ('minima', 'A')], 130.0), ([('prassi', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 121.0), ([('autorità', 'S'), ('competenti', 'A')], 116.0), ([('revisione', 'S'), ('totale', 'A')], 112.0), ([('lavoro', 'S'), ('forzato', 'A')], 110.0), ([('cure', 'S'), ('mediche', 'A')], 94.0), ([('paragrafo', 'S'), ('precedente', 'A')], 92.0), ([('proposte', 'S'), ('relative', 'A')], 79.0), ([('formazione', 'S'), ('professionale', 'A')], 76.0), ([('organizzazioni', 'S'), ('rappresentative', 'A')], 76.0), ([('lavoratori', 'S'), ('interessati', 'A')], 74.0), ([('convenzione', 'S'), ('internazionale', 'A')], 71.0)]
```

For every bigram of words is assigned one score, and the items in the list are ranked by their score.

How can I get the first 5 items with maximal value in the list?

Comment: Instead of re-posting, why not undelete your previous post? The contents are near identical.

Comment: You can edit a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is already sorted in descending order. So just slice the list to get your top five:

```
>>> lista[:5]
    [([('autorit\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('competente', 'A')], 580.0), ([('legislazione', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 313.0), ([('et\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('minima', 'A')], 130.0), ([('prassi', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 121.0), ([('autorit\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('competenti', 'A')], 116.0)]
```

If you want them without the score:

```
>>> [x[0] for x in lista[:5]]
[[('autorit\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('competente', 'A')], [('legislazione', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], [('et\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('minima', 'A')], [('prassi', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], [('autorit\xc3\xa0', 'S'), ('competenti', 'A')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
max_ngrams, max_value = ([('autorità', 'S'), ('competente', 'A')], 580.0)
```

so

```
max_value = 580.0
```

There is no other bigram with a superior score so it is normal you only get this one

Comment: But if I want all the maximal vlaues in the list?

Comment: It appears your list is sorted in a decreasing order here, so your first element is the maximum value. so you will not find any other element.
You could do max_value * 0.5 for example so you will the have the first two results

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
lista = [([('autorità', 'S'), ('competente', 'A')], 580.0), ([('legislazione', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 313.0), ([('età', 'S'), ('minima', 'A')], 130.0), ([('prassi', 'S'), ('nazionale', 'A')], 121.0), ([('autorità', 'S'), ('competenti', 'A')], 116.0), ([('revisione', 'S'), ('totale', 'A')], 112.0), ([('lavoro', 'S'), ('forzato', 'A')], 110.0), ([('cure', 'S'), ('mediche', 'A')], 94.0), ([('paragrafo', 'S'), ('precedente', 'A')], 92.0), ([('proposte', 'S'), ('relative', 'A')], 79.0), ([('formazione', 'S'), ('professionale', 'A')], 76.0), ([('organizzazioni', 'S'), ('rappresentative', 'A')], 76.0), ([('lavoratori', 'S'), ('interessati', 'A')], 74.0), ([('convenzione', 'S'), ('internazionale', 'A')], 71.0)]

max_value = 0

count = 0

for index,value in enumerate(lista):

    if value[1]> max_value:

        max_value = value[1]

        count = index

print lista[count]
```

Comment: It returns only the first one